# How to set mindate and maxdate in winform Datagridview datetime picker Control?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I am using Winform And C#.

In that i added calander cell in datagridview control using below link code.

It perfectly working.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx.

My code for calendar control adding....

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
                {
                    row.Cells[4].Value = DateTime.Now;                    
                }
```

[image]

i know MinDate and MaxDate propriety available on normal control.

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Today;

dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears( 1 );
```

But I want to set min date and max date in all calander control in datagrid view column.

How to implement min and max date in datagridview datetime control for all rows.,

Please help me.,,

Updated Question

```
 public class CalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
        {

            public CalendarCell()
                : base()
            {
                // Use the short date format.
                this.Style.Format = "d";
            }

            // For Min And Max DATE
            public DateTime MaxDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime MinDate { get; set; }

            public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
                initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
            {
                // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
                base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
                    dataGridViewCellStyle);
                CalendarEditingControl ctl =
                    DataGridView.EditingControl as CalendarEditingControl;

                // For Min And Max DATE
                ctl.MinDate = MinDate;
                ctl.MaxDate = MaxDate;

                // Use the default row value when Value property is null.
                if (this.Value == null)
                {
                    ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.DefaultNewRowValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.Value;
                }
            }
```

My Code,..

But I am not get MinDate and MaxDate Propriety. What is my mistake...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You already answered it yourself, use the properties intended for that purpose. What problem are you having doing this?

Comment: I know the mindate maxdate propriety is in datetime picker. But I don't know how to implement this in datagridview column. Did you understand my problem?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new properties to the `CalendarColumn` class:

```
public DateTime MinDate { get; set; }
public DateTime MaxDate { get; set; }
```

And in the `InitializeEditingControl` control, add the following code:

```
ctl.MinDate = this.MinDate;
ctl.MaxDate = this.MaxDate;
```

You can then set these properties on the column, and they will be reflected in the `DateTimePicker`s (note that it will be taken into account only for new cells)

Comment: how i set mindate maxdate like datetimepicker1.mindate = DateTime.Today;

Where and how to assign value.

Comment: You set the property on the column: `((CalendarColumn)dataGridView2.Columns["date"]).MinValue = ...`

Comment: I can't get the MinDate in property. What can i do?.

See my Updated Question.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't get the MinDate in property"?

Comment: The property was not shown in coding...
Its Ok. I set values in override function itself. Thanks

  ctl.MinDate = hp.currentAcademic_StartingDate;
                ctl.MaxDate = hp.currentAcademic_EndingDate;

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to the constructor of the CalendarEditingControl if you want to enforce that for all cells:

```
public CalendarEditingControl()
{
    this.MinDate = DateTime.Today;
    this.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1);
    this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
}
```

You could also expose some designer properties to make it more generic if you need to, but this might suffice for your usage.